# Best practice for core data function

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

What's the best design to use in an iPhone app that uses core data when you have several view controllers that make similar core data calls?

Currently I have an app which has several view controllers which all perform similar functions like adding objects to an entity, deleting an entity, etc.  I figure there are a few ways to handle this:

1. Each view controller has it's own addItem:blah class.  Downside is this results in some copy-pasta between the classes
2. Create a superclass which has the core data methods, and inherit from that class.  Override where necessary
3. Create a category so all instances of view controllers have those methods without needing to subclass
4. Create a data manager singleton which can be called.  Might be useful to have this so I can queue requests and do data management outside of each view controller.  Downside is this feels like a bad idea in general

Comment: Why does 4. feel like a bad idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CoreData and ViewControllers don't need to know about each other.

UIViewControllers are not traditional Controllers in the MVC world. They are more closely couple to Views - and I prefer to create them with this in mind,(most Apple example code has a lot of ModelController code - probably for simplicity of the examples).

I like to create ModelControllers and leave my ViewController managing my Views, and I give my ViewControllers an instance of my ModelController.

My ModelController will manage my Model, loading, editing, deleting etc... I still expose my Model classes to my ViewControllers, but Views NEVER leave the ViewController. You would never see a View in the ModelController.

The advantage of this is that if you later create an iPad app - your model and how it behaves is completely independent from your ViewControllers, so when you create some new UIViewControllers for your iPad app - you can plug in your ModelControllers.

Your ModelController could have a parent class that has your duplicate CRUD methods.

Alternatively....

A library called MagicalRecord https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord adds the Active Record pattern to NSManagedObjects.